# Elasticsearch and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I want to eventually create drillable dashboards of teams, their members and member's skills levels.

If it were a RDBMS I would create the following but I'm not sure how to structure the tables into documents so I can have it as a kibana dashboard:

```
• Team
    ○ String ID:TeamName  [one team is the bench?]
    ○ String Array:MemberID
    ○ String Array:SkillID
• Member
    ○ String ID:PersonnelID
    ○ String:MemberName
• Skill
    ○ String ID:Skill
    ○ String: Description

• MemberSkill
    ○ String: MemberID
    ○ String: SkillID
    ○ Number: Skill Level
    ○ DateTime: Updated Date
• [TeamMembers] Join table for one to many
• [TeamSkills]  Join table for one to many
```

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) describes 4 ways of dealing with joins in elasticsearch.

Kibana doesn't do anything like this that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using nested objects and later use nested query, nested aggregations to report on things

For example, your stuff may be structured like

```
  "teams": [
{
  "name": "Ninja warriors",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "c#",
          "level": 5
        },
        {
          "name":"JS",
          "level":7
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Ryan",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "c#",
          "level": 1
        },
        {
          "name":"JS",
          "level":8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]

where teams, members, skills are all nested objects.